# The positivity of matrix with one parameter changing

Tags: matrices

Set
$$D=\begin{bmatrix}0\\d_{1}&0\\d_{2}&d_{1}&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\ddots\\d_{n}&d_{n-1}&\cdots&d_{1}&0\end{bmatrix}$$
and
$$W(\alpha)=(I-\alpha D)^{-1}-\frac{1}{2}I$$
$$\Sigma(\alpha)=W(\alpha)+W^{*}(\alpha)$$
where $\alpha$ is a real number in $[0,1]$, $*$ represents conjugate transpose.

The question is:

suppose $$\Sigma(1)>0$$, if we can think $$\Sigma(\alpha)>0$$ with $\alpha $ changing from $0$ to $1$ ? Thanks a lot

I know that $W(\alpha)$ is also a lower triangular matrix with diagonal elements $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: It is pretty easy to see that $\Sigma(\alpha)$ is positive definite at $\alpha = 0$ by construction, and you "suppose" that $\Sigma(1)$ also is positive definite.  The problem thus seems to ask whether intermediate values $0\lt \alpha \lt 1$ will also produce positive definite matrices.  If you like, I can tweak the wording of your Question to make that a bit clearer.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C=(I-\alpha D)$. Then
\begin{align}
\Sigma(\alpha)
&= (C^\ast)^{-1} + C^{-1} - I\\
&= (C^\ast)^{-1}(C + C^\ast - C^\ast C)C^{-1}\\
&= (C^\ast)^{-1}\left[I-(C^\ast-I)(C-I)\right]C^{-1}\\
&= (C^\ast)^{-1}(I-\alpha^2D^\ast D)C^{-1}\\
\end{align}
Since $\Sigma(1)\succ0$, we must have $I\succ D^\ast D$. Hence $I-\alpha^2D^\ast D$ and in turn $\Sigma(\alpha)$ are positive definite for every $-1\le\alpha\le1$.